# laravel wordpress blog install at blog.example.com how?

Tags: wordpress, laravel, nginx, blogs

I want to install a wordpress blog alongside my laravel website, at the address http://blog.example.com.  I have read online examples where wordpress is installed at http://www.example.com/blog and then conditions are added to nginx config file.  I understand it would be a lot easier if I install wordpress to http://blog.example.com and do 301 redirects?  Could someone explain how to go about doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: Its too broad a question to answer here. You should try it yourself and post questions related to specific areas you are struggling. To get you started, I would have two root directories say `var/www/blog.example.com` and `/var/www/example.com` and have 2 nginx virtual hosts. Inside the nginx virtual hosts each would have a different `server_name` and `root`.